# How to modify line spacing per entry of bibliography?

Tags: spacing, bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am using [Easy-Thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis/) template to write my thesis. I downloaded this template from writelatex website.

I am using `natbib` to format my bibliography style. This generate nice layout for the bibliography. But what I find is the distance between lines in a bibliography entry. The spacing between lines in a entry is about `4pt`. I want them to be close to each other. The next entry should be about `10pt` apart. What now I have is the spacing between all the lines (within entry and between entries) is the same through out whole bibliography.

I have entered commands like

```
\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
```

But seems it doesnt help me.

Comment: Please give us a link to the template

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming the template is this one: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis/ (it is the only easy-thesis I've found).

The template uses `\setstretch{1.3}` which increases the baseline skip of a 1.3 factor. That's why you have "about `4pt`" between lines of the same bibliography entry.

To achieve what you want, it suffices to restore the normal baseline skip through the command

```
\setstretch{1}
```

and set the distance between items to `10pt` through the command

```
\setlength{\bibsep}{10pt}
```

In other words, if your `.bib` file is named `Bibliography.bib`, use the following lines to insert your bibliography in the document:

```
\begingroup
    \setlength{\bibsep}{10pt}
    \setstretch{1}
    \bibliography{Bibliography}
\endgroup
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{Thesis}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Bibliography.bib}
@article{art1,
author="First Last",
title="A fictitious journal article",
year=1900,
journal="Journal of nothingness",
volume=2,
pages="1-2"
}
@article{art2,
author="First Last",
title="A very very very very very very very very very very very very long journal article",
year=1900,
journal="Journal of nothingness",
volume=2,
pages="1-2"
}
@book{boo1,
author="Respectable Writer",
title="A silly book",
year=2000,
publisher="PublishCo",
address="Somewhere"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[super,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.3}

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-8]

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begingroup
    \setlength{\bibsep}{10pt}
    \setstretch{1}
    \bibliography{Bibliography}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Just in case I was wrong with the template and you get errors with `\setstretch{1}`, replace it with

```
\linespread{1}\selectfont
```

Comment: @HarishKumar In the beginning of the answer there's a link...

Comment: Thank you so much sir "karlkoeller". Your help perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: @Vijay You're welcome and thank you for the "sir".

Comment: I'm using bibtex, the `\setstretch{1}` did the job, but I think `\bibsep` is natbib, and it didn't work for me.