# How do I do this in LaTeX? "Single space within each reference entry and double space between reference entries."

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

For works cited, I need to follow this guideline: "Single space within each reference entry and double space between reference entries."

I've tried (for several hours now) using bib packages and libraries, but nothing has worked. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us (a lot) more about your document. E.g., what's the default spacing of your document (singlespacing, doublespacing, something else?), and how is this spacing achieved? Do you use a citation management package? If so, which? Do you build the bibliography by hand (I hope you don't...) or do you use a tool, e.g., bibtex or biblatex. Please be specific.

Comment: Can you provide the community with a minimal document we can use as a starting point? Include a number of citations so we can experiment with the code. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should be able to find the answere here. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163559/how-to-modify-line-spacing-per-entry-of-bibliography

Comment: @Mico Any thoughts here? To me, the question is unclear.

Comment: @Johannes_B - I agree with your view that the question simply isn't clear enough to afford a stab at an answer; I've voted accordingly.